# Hibernate generating Oracle queries with "(+)" operator instead join

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have to do some improvements to a legacy project using Hibernate 5.0.9 with Oracle database. I noticed that hibernate are generating queries like that

```
select a.id, b.id
from a, b
where a.b_id = b.id(+)
```

instead of

```
select a.id, b.id
from a left join b on a.b_id = b.id
```

for a code like this

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.createAlias("a.b", "b", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria = criteria.setProjection(
       Projections.projectionList()
         .add(Projections.property("a.id"))
         .add(Projections.property("b.id"))
  );

criteria.list();
```

At least for me, the "(+)" is complicated to read.
In other project with same Hibernate version, the "joins" are generated normally.

Is this a Hibernate configuration?

Comment: It might be the hibernate dialect. The setting is "hibernate.dialect". There are at.least  four different Oracle dialects. Try the one that matches your Oracle version. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html

Comment: It was really the dialect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion, adding the dialect information in persistence.xml solved the problem.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" />
```